# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xfc.

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, twilio

**I got this error while initiating the call using Twilio SDK.**

```
02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xfc
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: '100.90.133.117���*�'
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "Thread-1849" prio=5 tid=43 Runnable
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x1e1b5560 self=0xb8b125b0
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=27495 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb87bb970
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 794242861 121820754 4071 ) utm=53 stm=26 core=0 HZ=100
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xa3e5e000-0xa3e60000 stackSize=1012KB
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00005b65  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+85)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00002e92  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+34)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 003cc028  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+136)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 00394c0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+285)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 00100c91  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1025)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 0010185f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+111)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 001065ae  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(bool, char const*, ...) (.constprop.130)+3070)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 0010c8be  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+94)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 00047560  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 00069b4d  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 0005f220  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 0012e760  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 000b5726  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #13 pc 00061d3e  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #14 pc 00061d8b  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #15 pc 00123a3c  /data/app/com.bd.speakreader-2/lib/x86/libtwilio-native.so (???)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #16 pc 00037cdb  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+59)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #17 pc 00032fba  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+26)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #18 pc 00011df6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   (no managed stack frames)
    02-20 11:19:51.366: A/art(27475): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
    02-20 11:19:52.496: A/art(27475): art/runtime/runtime.cc:285] Runtime aborting...
    02-20 11:19:52.496: A/art(27475): art/runtime/runtime.cc:285] Aborting thread:
```

**The same code works well in Andorid Kitkat, but is giving crashed in Android Lollipop..! Please help !**

Comment: Either the string contents changed, or the VM behavior became more restrictive. Either way, you can't pass that string (which looks like an IP address with garbage at the end) to NewStringUTF. If you didn't provide that string to libtwilio somehow, then the library itself may need to be updated.

Comment: but the library has been provided by the twilio team only .. how can we update that library on our own .. ?

Comment: Hi, twilio developer evangelist here. Which library are you trying to use? And where did you download it from. Also, it would be useful if you could update the question with some of the code you're trying to use.

Comment: i downloaded the latest twilio SDK from here   https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android  for Android. I am using the simple code for calling. Just passing the client name in the phone.connect method

Comment: Same issue here. Happening once every 2 or 3 times when starting a call from Lollipop or Marshmallow (no issues receiving calls). App stops even if device.connect is between try/catch. Seems to be working fine with prior versions of Android.